Keep Getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'clean' of null, js engine: hermes Using react-native-image-filter-kit
Keep getting Keep Getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'clean' of null, js engine: hermes when trying to implement a simple  component in react native expo project.
I am using react native and expo, I have imported react-native-image-filter-kit because I would like to allow a user to control certain aspects of an image such as brightness. Keeping it simple and going with the exact example on the github examples of this particular component
(link to the example): https://github.com/iyegoroff/react-native-image-filter-kit/blob/master/examples/CustomFilter/src/App.tsx
Here is my code I'll keep it simple to just the page I am working on:
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native';
import Feather from '@expo/vector-icons/Feather';
import StyledIconContainer from '../styledIconContainer';
import { Fontisto } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { ImageFilter } from 'react-native-image-filter-kit';
import FontAwesome5 from '@expo/vector-icons/FontAwesome5';
import { useState } from 'react';
interface ImageInfo {
  uri: string;
  width: number;
  height: number;
  type: string | undefined;
}
interface ImageData {
  imageInfo: ImageInfo;
  // String for %age of each for positioning
  top: number;
  left: number;
}
interface FilterMenuProps {
  menuToggle: () => void,
  activeImage: ImageData
}

const FilterMenu: React.FC<FilterMenuProps> = ({menuToggle}) => {

  const [toggleFilter1, setToggleFilter1] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const handleCloseMenu = () => {
    menuToggle();
  }

  const handleToggleFilter1 = () => {
    setToggleFilter1(!toggleFilter1);
  }
  const localImage = require('../../assets/images/welcome.png');

  return (
    <View style={styles.menuLayout}>

      <View style={styles.close}>

          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleCloseMenu()}>
            <Fontisto name={'close'} size={25}/>
          </TouchableOpacity>

      </View>

      <View style={styles.bottomToolbar}>

        <StyledIconContainer dimensions={40}>

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleToggleFilter1()}>
          <Feather name={'sunrise'} size={15}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
 
          <FontAwesome5 name={'eraser'} size={15}/>
          <FontAwesome5 name={'eraser'} size={15}/>
          <FontAwesome5 name={'eraser'} size={15}/>
          <FontAwesome5 name={'eraser'} size={15}/>
          <FontAwesome5 name={'eraser'} size={15}/>
          <FontAwesome5 name={'eraser'} size={15}/>

          <ImageFilter config={{name: 'Brightness', amount: 1, image: <Image source=        {require('../../assets/images/welcome.png')}/>}}/>

        </StyledIconContainer>

      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

export default FilterMenu;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  image: {
    display: 'flex'
  },
  bottomToolbar: {
    display: 'flex',
flexWrap: 'wrap',
flexDirection: 'row',
justifyContent: 'center',
gap: 40,
rowGap: 30,
padding: 30,
borderWidth: 1,
borderColor: 'pink',
borderRadius: 30
  },
  menuLayout: {
display: 'flex',
flexWrap: 'wrap',
flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  close: {
position: 'absolute',
right: '-1%',
top: '8%',
zIndex: 9999 
  },
})


{
  "name": "elemental_editor_2",
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
"start": "expo start",
"reset-project": "node ./scripts/reset-project.js",
"android": "expo start --android",
"ios": "expo start --ios",
"web": "expo start --web",
"test": "jest --watchAll",
"lint": "expo lint"
  },
  "jest": {
"preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
"@expo-google-fonts/inter": "^0.2.3",
"@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.0",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.18",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.4.1",
"expo": "~51.0.24",
"expo-constants": "~16.0.2",
"expo-file-system": "~17.0.1",
"expo-font": "~12.0.9",
"expo-image-picker": "~15.0.7",
"expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
"expo-router": "~3.5.20",
"expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.5",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
"expo-system-ui": "~3.0.7",
"expo-web-browser": "~13.0.3",
"npm": "~10.8.2",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-dom": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "^0.74.3",
"react-native-image-filter-kit": "^0.8.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "~4.10.5",
"react-native-screens": "^3.31.1",
"react-native-svg": "~15.2.0",
"react-native-web": "~0.19.10",
"react-navigation": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
"@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
"@types/react": "~18.2.45",
"@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.7",
"jest": "^29.2.1",
"jest-expo": "~51.0.2",
"react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
"typescript": "~5.3.3"
  },
  "private": true
}

I have tried simplifying my  as much as possible to where it only includes brightness level and adding my image link directly rather than using useStates or anything.
Created a const config with the config data I use within the component and console.logging it which actually works great!
I validate all my packages are up to date or compatible with each other because expo is really good at keeping me on the same page for that type of stuff.
But the moment I include the config or hardcode it, I get this error and I have been working at this for 2 days now. Any ideas?
PS if you are wodnering why my formatting is horrible it is because stack overflow told me I could not post until I indent my code by 4 spaces or use the code option in the toolbar or use ctrl k short cut.
I scoured and there is no option for code and ctrl k just added `` around it and did not do anything to allow me to post it so I manually had to adjust it and didn't want to do any line that it didn't force me to. Sorry about that!
